# How do you get a dragon head in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get a dragon head in the Minecraft (survival mode)? I really need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can find Dragon Heads on End Ships.

**How to locate an End Ship**

After you kill the ender dragon, you might spot two clusters of bedrock with a portal in the center off the edge of the island- these lead to the outer islands of the End.  The portals look like this:

[image]

It's extremely hard to get in them, as you can see the gap for the portal is only one block tall (use of an ender pearl is recommended!).  If you can't, the outer islands are ~1000 meters away from the central island, so lots of stacks of some easy-to-obtain block like dirt or cobblestone could get you there too.  Also, you can make a [flying machine.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Flying_technologies), make it go outwards from the islands, and AFK for a few minutes. The outer islands look like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are many dips in between the islands, you'll need a lot of blocks.  Eventually, you'll come across this:

[image]

which is an End City.  Up in the air, you might see an end ship:

[image]

On the very front, you'll see a Dragon Head...Feather Falling is extremely recommended!

*Thank you for the suggestions, commenters!*

Comment: "It's extremely hard to get in them", uuhm, throw an ender pearl in it?

Comment: use slimeblock and piston flying machine. and go AFK for few minutes

Comment: True, I mean other methods.  Though you don't want to obtain the ender pearls in the end, since you'll have an Endermen swarm chasing you...

Comment: @Fennekin Should have thought of that, I'll add that...

Comment: "It's extremely hard to get in them": It's unbreakable bedrock. The only way to get in them is to break the bedrock in creative or throw and enderpearl.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_head), dragon heads will generate on [End Ships](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city#End_ship). To quote:

> A dragon head can also be seen at the bow of the ship, making this currently the only natural way to obtain the beast's head.

End Ships can be found in an [End City](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_city), which randomly generate on outer Islands in the End. To quote:

> End cities naturally and randomly generate in the outer islands of the End, which are accessible via the end gateway portal that generates after killing the ender dragon. They are fairly rare; one can travel for thousands of blocks without encountering a city.

Comment: where is the ship??

Comment: @sallyherring I have edited the answer to include where to find End Ships and End Cities.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @sallyherring if the answer helps you, click the check mark. This will help people with the same problem find an answer faster

Answer (score -1):

I found a dragon head on the very very edge of the end ship. I had to put blocks underneath it in order to catch it. check everywhere!

Answer (score -3):

After you beat the ender dragon there will be a thing floating in the sky that has a small portal in it ender pearl to it then you will be on a new island find a end city there should be a pirate ship very close to it at the front of the ship you will find the head it will be where the mermaid should be floating.